# Calculadora com validação JavaScript (nao consigo achar o erro)

Tags: javascript

Calculadora

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #div1{
            text-align:center;
            border:1px solid black;
            width:20%;
            height:200px;
            position:absolute;
            left:40%;
        }

        #campo1,#campo2{
            width:40px;
            margin:5px;
        }

        #btn1,#btn2, #btn3, #btn4{
            margin:3px;
        }

        #result{                
            float:center;

        }
    </style>


    <script language="javascript">


        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("campo1").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("campo2").value);
        var soma = (num1+num2);
        var subtracao = (num1-num2);
        var multiplicacao = (num1*num2);
        var divisao = (num1/num2);

        function somar(){
            if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)){
                alert("Os campos devem conter apenas numeros");
            }
            else{
                document.getElementByID("valorFinal").innerHTML = soma;         
            }
        }

        function subtrair(){
            if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2){
                alert("Os campos devem conter apenas numeros");
            }
            else{
                document.getElementByID("valorFinal").innerHTML = subtracao;            
            }
        }

        function multiplicar(){ 
            if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2){
                alert("Os campos devem conter apenas numeros");
            }
            else{
                document.getElementByID("valorFinal").innerHTML = multiplicao;          
            }
        }

        function dividir(){ 
            if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2){
                alert("Os campos devem conter apenas numeros");
            }
            else{
                document.getElementByID("valorFinal").innerHTML = divisao;          
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>

    <input type="text" id="campo1" />
    <input type="text" id="campo2" /><br />

    <input type="button" value="+" id="btn1" onClick="somar()">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="btn2" onClick="subtrair()">
    <input type="button" value="*" id="btn3" onClick="multiplicar()">
    <input type="button" value="/" id="btn4" onClick="dividir()"><br />

    <b><label id="result">Resultado: </label></b>

    <p id="valorFinal"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quando o browser lê estas linhas:

```
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("campo1").value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("campo2").value);
```

ele lê imediatamente o valor desses inputs e guarda nas variáveis. Ele faz isso uma vez e nunca mais. Então o que acontece é que quando "fazes contas" os valores que possas ter escrito nos inputs não estão nas variáveis `num1` e `num2`. Contudo se guardares apontadores ao próprio elemento podes ir buscar o valor mais tarde.

Tens que atualizar esses valores ou a cada vez que fazes uma conta ou a cada vez que um input mudar o valor.

Fazendo um pouco DRY ao código poderia ficar assim:

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("campo1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("campo2");
var mostrador = document.getElementById("valorFinal");

function calculadora(fn) {
    var num1 = parseInt(input1.value, 10);
    var num2 = parseInt(input2.value, 10);
    if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) alert("Os campos devem conter apenas numeros");
    else mostrador.innerHTML = fn(num1, num2);
}

function somar(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function subtrair(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function multiplicar(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}

function dividir(a, b) {
    return a / b;
}
```

```css
 #div1 {
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 40%;
     height: 200px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 40%;
 }
 
 #campo1,
 #campo2 {
     width: 40px;
     margin: 5px;
 }
 
 #btn1,
 #btn2,
 #btn3,
 #btn4 {
     margin: 3px;
 }
 
 #result {
     float: center;
 }
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>

    <input type="text" id="campo1" />
    <input type="text" id="campo2" />
    <br />

    <input type="button" value="+" id="btn1" onClick="calculadora(somar)">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="btn2" onClick="calculadora(subtrair)">
    <input type="button" value="*" id="btn3" onClick="calculadora(multiplicar)">
    <input type="button" value="/" id="btn4" onClick="calculadora(dividir)">
    <br />

    <b><label id="result">Resultado: </label></b>

    <p id="valorFinal"></p>
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7k0mL6w7/

Repara que o código como está deve estar no final do `<body>` para o JavaScript encontrar os elementos que procura no DOM.

Answer (score -2):

```
function calcular(valor, index) {

var num1 = document.getElementById("texto1").value

var num2 = document.getElementById("texto2").value


//var num1 = 10
//var num2 = 30


num1 = Number(num1)
num2 = Number(num2)


var soma = num1 + num2
var subtracao = num1 - num2
var multiplicacao = num1 * num2
var divisao = num1 / num2
//-------------------------------


if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)){
    alert("Os campos devem conter apenas numeros");
}

else if (index === "+") {


    let somar = document.getElementById('display').value = soma

    document.getElementById('display').value = somar


}

else  if (index === "-") {


    let subtrair = document.getElementById('display').value = subtracao

    document.getElementById('display').value = subtrair


}
else  if (index === "*") {


    let multiplicar = document.getElementById('display').value = multiplicacao

    document.getElementById('display').value = multiplicar


}
else  if (index === "/") {


    let dividir = document.getElementById('display').value = divisao

    document.getElementById('display').value = dividir
}

}

</script>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você [edit] e incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/100416).